# gnome shell overview search not showing anything other than apps

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-panel, 23.04

[shell overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pb1k.png)
[My settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JOsl.png)

I am fairly new to linux. I hope somebody can help me